# Sum of modified Bessel functions of the second kind

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, bessel-functions

Does anyone have any suggestions for solving the following sum:
$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m^{2a-\frac{1}2}} K_{a}(m\, b)$$
where $a$ and $b$ are both real and positive.

Comment: Google Bessel functions, find a good series or integral representation, interchange with the sum & hope you get lucky.

Comment: Unfortunately, the integral representation of the Bessel function didn't help since I wasn't able to perform the sum afterward.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
K_{ \alpha}(x)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x \cosh t} cosh( \alpha t) dt
\end{eqnarray*}
leads to the sum
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{u^m}{m^{2a-\frac{1}{2}}} 
\end{eqnarray*}
This sum is a bit hard ... so we did not get lucky there $ \ddot \frown $

Answer (score 0):

Well, we know that:

$$\text{K}_\sigma\left(x\right):=\int_0^\infty\frac{\cosh\left(\sigma t\right)}{\exp\left(x\cosh\left(t\right)\right)}\space\text{d}t\tag1$$

So, we get:

$$\mathscr{I}:=\sum_{\text{m}=1}^\infty\frac{\text{K}_\text{a}\left(\text{b}\cdot\text{m}\right)}{\text{m}^{2\text{a}-\frac{1}{2}}}=\sum_{\text{m}=1}^\infty\left\{\frac{1}{\text{m}^{2\text{a}-\frac{1}{2}}}\cdot\int_0^\infty\frac{\cosh\left(\text{a}\cdot t\right)}{\exp\left(\text{b}\cdot\text{m}\cdot\cosh\left(t\right)\right)}\space\text{d}t\right\}=$$
$$\int_0^\infty\cosh\left(\text{a}\cdot t\right)\cdot\left\{\sum_{\text{m}=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\text{m}^{2\text{a}-\frac{1}{2}}}\cdot\frac{1}{\exp\left(\text{b}\cdot\text{m}\cdot\cosh\left(t\right)\right)}\right\}\space\text{d}t\tag2$$

Let $\text{u}=\text{b}\cdot\cosh\left(t\right)$so we get:

$$\sum_{\text{m}=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\text{m}^{2\text{a}-\frac{1}{2}}}\cdot\frac{1}{\exp\left(\text{u}\cdot\text{m}\right)}\tag3$$

Comment: $u = b \cosh(t)$ then what ?

Comment: I don't quite see how to perform the integral in (2) either.